# Foreach do action static function by "name" in laravel :x

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Someone please help me enlighten in LARAVEL !!!

in LARAVEL controller i difine static function like this :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\MyAPI;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class MyAPIController extends Controller {

    const acceptMethod = ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE']

    public function handler(Request $request) {
           $acceptMethod = self::acceptMethod;
           $ctrl = new PromotionController;
           $method = $request->method()

         // This is my question :((
          if ($method == 'GET')
              $ctrl::read($request);
          if ($method == 'GET')
              $ctrl::post($request);
          $ctrl::put($request);
          ... 

          //I want to be like this : 
           foreach($acceptMethod as $method) {
              // Not work 
               $ctrl::($method)($request);
           }


    }

    public static function read(Request $request) {
        return something;
    }

    public static function post(Request $request) {
        return ...;
    }

    public static function put(Request $request) {
        return ...;
    }

    public static function delete(Request $request) {
        return ...;
    }

}
```

And then i must use controll like :

```
  if ($method == 'get')
      $ctrl::read($request);
  if ($method == 'post')
      $ctrl::post($request);
  $ctrl::put($request);
```

But i have a array :

and i want to be like this :

```
 $acceptMethod = ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'];   
 foreach($acceptMethod as $functionName) {
    // Not work 
    $ctrl::$functionName($request);
 }
```

Is there any way to make this possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use {};

Please, try this inside the loop:

```
$fn = strtolower($functionName)
$ctrl::{$fn}($request);
```

You can call a attribute too..

$instance->{'attribute_name'};

Answer (score 0):

### Routes

The proper way to do it would be to define a RESTful resource for your object so you get all the routes RESTfully. In your routes/api.php

```
Route::resource('thing','MyAPIController');
```

That will magically route:

- GET api/thing to index()
- GET api/thing/create to create()
- POST api/thing to store()
- GET api/thing/{id} to show($id)
- GET api/thing/{id}/edit to edit()
- PATCH api/thing/{id} to update()
- DELETE api/thing/{id} to destroy()

If you have multiple objects to REST, you'd just add a controller for each.

### Whats wrong $ctrl::{$fn}($request)

Injection is always on the OWASP top 10 each year, and this opens up potential [function injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Function_Injection).  You can mitigate that risk by making sure you white list the method.  But, I'd rather just use Laravel the way it was intended.